# Counting the maximum number of real zeros of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a real function defined as
$$f(x)= (a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2) \ln x+(a_3+a_4x) \arctan x +a_5+a_6x^2.$$
Which theorem can be used to determine the maximum number of zeros that the function $f(x)$ can have?

Comment: @JeanMarie The derivative $f'$ is not generally rational for this function. Since we have terms of the form $p(x)\ln x$ and $p(x) \arctan x$ for polynomial $p(x)$, the product rule means that we fail to differentiate out the non-polynomial terms.

Comment: @Jam You are perfectly right. I erase my silly comment.

Comment: I found this corollary
"Let f be a function with n−1 continuous derivatives on an interval I and the n-th derivative on its interior Int( I ). If the n-th derivative f (n) has k distinct zero points in I, then f can have at most k+n distinct zero points in I".  But i don't find its proof. Is it true?